# RUN headful playwright in an rdp as root targeting a non root user's $DISPLAY

Tags: node.js, playwright, xserver, xrdp

i want to RUN a simple nodejs script which runs headful playwright in a linux RDP running xrdp with gnome as root , and i want to target a non root user's $DISPLAY

the goal is i don't want the rdp user to have access to the script so i place them in root session and i run the express server as root , and when i run it as root the rdp non root user would see the headful browser opening when he accesses the RDP in a client

below  works when the non root user is running the express server

as root don't work i get the following error when i run it  : Missing X server or $DISPLAY

i am i triggering the script with an http request

```
import playwright from 'playwright';

const data = exec(
  "loginctl show-session $(loginctl -a show-user rdp | grep Display | sed 's/Display.//g') | grep Display | sed 's/Display.//g'",
);

if (data.stdout.length) {
  process.env['DISPLAY'] = data.stdout.replace(/\n/g, ''); // sets the DISPLAY env to for say :10.0
}



(async () => {
  // Setup
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    headless:false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // The actual interesting bit
  await page.goto('https://example.com/');

  // Teardown
  await browser.close();
})()
```